# subprocess or multithreading or threading pool

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm going to run the command line utility multiple times in parallel using Python.
I know that `multithreading` is better to use for I/O operations, `multiprocessing` - for CPU oriented operations.

But what should I use for parallel `subprocess.run`?
I also know that I can create a pool from the `subprocess` module, but how is it different from pools from the multiprocessing and threading modules? And why shouldn't I just put `subprocess.run` function into multiprocessing or threading pools?

Or maybe there are some criteria when it is better to put a utility run cmd into a pool of threads or processes?

(In my case, I'm going to run the "ffmpeg" utility)

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` is the backgrounded version of `subprocess.run`; there's a decent chance you need neither threads nor process pools.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like this, I tend to run subprocesses from a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, basically because it's easy.

Example (from [here](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/main/dicom2jpg.py)):

```
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial
import argparse
import concurrent.futures as cf
import logging
import os
import subprocess as sp
import sys

__version__ = "2021.09.19"


def main():
    """
    Entry point for dicom2jpg.
    """
    args = setup()
    if not args.fn:
        logging.error("no files to process")
        sys.exit(1)
    if args.quality != 80:
        logging.info(f"quality set to {args.quality}")
    if args.level:
        logging.info("applying level correction.")
    convert_partial = partial(convert, quality=args.quality, level=args.level)
    starttime = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
    logging.info(f"started at {starttime}.")
    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as tp:
        for infn, outfn, rv in tp.map(convert_partial, args.fn):
            logging.info(f"finished conversion of {infn} to {outfn} (returned {rv})")
    endtime = str(datetime.now())[:-7]
    logging.info(f"completed at {endtime}.")


def setup():
    """Parse command-line arguments."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument(
        "--log",
        default="warning",
        choices=["debug", "info", "warning", "error"],
        help="logging level (defaults to 'warning')",
    )
    parser.add_argument("-v", "--version", action="version", version=__version__)
    parser.add_argument(
        "-l",
        "--level",
        action="store_true",
        default=False,
        help="Correct color levels (default: no)",
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-q", "--quality", type=int, default=80, help="JPEG quailty level (default: 80)"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "fn", nargs="*", metavar="filename", help="DICOM files to process"
    )
    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=getattr(logging, args.log.upper(), None),
        format="%(levelname)s: %(message)s",
    )
    logging.debug(f"command line arguments = {sys.argv}")
    logging.debug(f"parsed arguments = {args}")
    # Check for requisites
    try:
        sp.run(["convert"], stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
        logging.info("found “convert”")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logging.error("the program “convert” cannot be found")
        sys.exit(1)
    return args


def convert(filename, quality, level):
    """
    Convert a DICOM file to a JPEG file.
    Removing the blank areas from the Philips detector.
    Arguments:
        filename: name of the file to convert.
        quality: JPEG quality to apply
        level: Boolean to indicate whether level adustment should be done.
    Returns:
        Tuple of (input filename, output filename, convert return value)
    """
    outname = filename.strip() + ".jpg"
    size = "1574x2048"
    args = [
        "convert",
        filename,
        "-units",
        "PixelsPerInch",
        "-density",
        "300",
        "-depth",
        "8",
        "-crop",
        size + "+232+0",
        "-page",
        size + "+0+0",
        "-auto-gamma",
        "-quality",
        str(quality),
    ]
    if level:
        args += ["-level", "-35%,70%,0.5"]
    args.append(outname)
    cp = sp.run(args, stdout=sp.DEVNULL, stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
    return (filename, outname, cp.returncode)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Alternatively, you can manage a bunch of subprocesses (in the form of `Popen` objects) directly, as shown below.
(This was older code, now modified for Python 3)

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from time import sleep


def checkfor(args):
    """Make sure that a program necessary for using this script is
    available.
    Arguments:
    args -- string or list of strings of commands. A single string may
            not contain spaces.
    """
    if isinstance(args, str):
        if " " in args:
            raise ValueError("No spaces in single command allowed.")
        args = [args]
    try:
        with open("/dev/null", "w") as bb:
            subprocess.check_call(args, stdout=bb, stderr=bb)
    except Exception:
        print("Required program '{}' not found! exiting.".format(args[0]))
        sys.exit(1)


def startconvert(fname):
    """Use the convert(1) program from the ImageMagick suite to convert the
    image and crop it."""
    size = "1574x2048"
    args = [
        "convert",
        fname,
        "-units",
        "PixelsPerInch",
        "-density",
        "300",
        "-crop",
        size + "+232+0",
        "-page",
        size + "+0+0",
        fname + ".png",
    ]
    with open("/dev/null") as bb:
        p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=bb, stderr=bb)
    print("Start processing", fname)
    return (fname, p)


def manageprocs(proclist):
    """Check a list of subprocesses for processes that have ended and
    remove them from the list.
    """
    for it in proclist:
        fn, pr = it
        result = pr.poll()
        if result is not None:
            proclist.remove(it)
            if result == 0:
                print("Finished processing", fn)
            else:
                s = "The conversion of {} exited with error code {}."
                print(s.format(fn, result))
    sleep(0.5)


def main(argv):
    """Main program.
    Keyword arguments:
    argv -- command line arguments
    """
    if len(argv) == 1:
        path, binary = os.path.split(argv[0])
        print("Usage: {} [file ...]".format(binary))
        sys.exit(0)
    del argv[0]  # delete the name of the script.
    checkfor("convert")
    procs = []
    maxprocs = cpu_count()
    for ifile in argv:
        while len(procs) == maxprocs:
            manageprocs(procs)
        procs.append(startconvert(ifile))
    while len(procs) > 0:
        manageprocs(procs)


# This is the main program ##
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```